Upvoting Good Posts Even if I Don’t Fully Understand Them
Many-a-times, when I come across good or excellent questions or answers I only partially understand or don’t understand at all, I have upvoted them. For example, $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$, $(5)$, $(6)$, $(7)$. I judge the quality of such posts by the number of upvotes received, and when it is fairly high $\big{(}$more than $5\big{)}$ or if the answer has received a bounty, I don’t give a second thought in upvoting it. I would like to know whether this practice is encouraged or not.

"I judge the quality of such posts by the number of upvotes received," I don't think that's a good idea. But I will occasionally upvote a post that I don't fully understand when I can see that it is nicely written up, or if I think it's a good question for the site that's sufficiently well written. I.e. I do it when I have some basis for making a positive judgement on the question. But I don't get the point of up voting something based solely on other people's previous evaluations.

And sometimes highly upvoted answers are plain wrong...

You’re a high school student. What then, is your reason for upvoting answers (which often involve college-level math) that you do not understand? Sounds ridiculous to me.

@CraniumClamp I used to believe that good answers should be upvoted to reward the efforts of the poster, but now as you all have said, I have understood that I should only vote posts if I find it be useful, have fully understood it and checked it to be of good quality.

I would not use "number of upvotes" as a flawless indicator of quality.  The Batman question got $465$ upvotes, for instance.  If you can't judge the merits of a post on your own, there's no need to provide an opinion.

@lulu For the record the Batman question has 644 upvotes.  It also has 179 downvotes.

What you propose would only exacerbate one of the major problems with voting - its temporal skewing, i.e. earlier posted answers get more exposure than later posted answers so often get more votes even if a (much) later posted answer is (much) higher quality.  Btw, an extreme example of the behavior you propose often occurs in questions on the hot network  list - where infrequent ("drive by") users simply pile on votes to popular answers - even if they don't understand them (and this only occurs during a short initial period so votes on later answers are skewed even further than normal).

"...  should be upvoted to reward the efforts of the poster". Despite the fact that the site is heavily "gamified", the goal here is not to amass the highest rep total, but to make the site as good as possible - the rep points are only good when they motivate people to improve the site. I know when you're starting out it seems like points are the goal, but if you stick around you'll see lower-rep users who make the site great and worth visiting and re-visiting.

As a h.s. student probably the best thing you can do for now is to read and learn, and start seeing if you can come up with your own answers for some questions. If you can tell that an answer is correct, and well-written, definitely give an up-vote. And as a high-school student, your contribution is noting when an answer is especially clear for someone at your level - let others take care of the voting on Q's and A's that are outside of your range.

@JonathanZ thanks for the advices, I will definitely keep these points in mind.

This practice is actively discouraged, and likely breaches the code of conduct.
Stop doing it.
See 'Why is voting important?' and 'Disruptive use of tooling policy' for formal details.
If you are voting on a post for any reason other than its own quality, you are doing it wrong.
Basing it on...

who wrote the post? Wrong.

when the post was written? Wrong.

the number of votes it already has, or its overall score? Wrong.


When you vote "because everyone else voted for it", you are falsely inflating the apparent quality and usefulness of the post to others.
Ask what would happen if many other users voted like that. In this case, the answer is "votes become meaningless in telling others whether a post is good or bad", so, don't do it.

So I shouldn't upvote any post until I've fully checked it myself to be of good quality, even if it has comments like "nice question" or "wonderful solution"?

@MathGuy I think that Nij's answer was quite clear:  no, you should not upvote a post unless you, based on your own knowledge, believe it to be a good question or answer.  You should not base your voting on the voting of others or the comments of others.
